# VMXON on MAC OS X - refuses to work

Tags: macos, virtualization, hypervisor

I'm trying to run a hypervisor on my OS X 10.9.4 but the VMXON refuses to work.
My system specs: Intel core i5 2.4, 8gb ram

Ive done the following:
1) Checked if CPU supports VMX using cpuid.
2) Turned on all needed bits in CR0 and CR4 registers. Checked which bits needed to be turned on using 0x486, 0x488 and RDMSR.
3) Allocated memory for the VMX region using:

```
if ((vmxon_region = IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::inTaskWithOptions(kernel_task, kIOMemoryPhysicallyContiguous , 0x400, PAGE_SIZE)) == NULL) {
    IOLog("LOG : Failed to allocate memory. Aborting \n");
    return kIOReturnAborted;
}
```

4) Copied to VMX REV ID to the first 4 bytes of the region using:

(vmx_rev_id contains the vmx version ID taken from rdmsr of 0x480 low part. 
In my case (Core i5) the value is 12HEX)

```
    if ((vmxon_region->writeBytes(0, &vmx_rev_id, sizeof(int))) < sizeof(int)) {
        IOLog("LOG : Failed to write to the vmx region. Aborting. \n");
        return kIOReturnAborted;
    }
```

I zeroed the rest of the bytes just to be safe (Don't know if it is really necessary).

The Last thing I did was to launch vmxon with:

```
uint64_t physicalAddr = vmxon_region->getPhysicalAddress();

asm volatile("vmxon %0; "::"g"(&physicalAddr));
asm volatile("jbe vmxon_fail\n");
vmxon_success = 1;
asm volatile("jmp vmxon_finish\n"
             "vmxon_fail:\n"
             "pushfq\n"
             );
asm volatile ("popq %0\n"
              :
              :"m"(rflags_value)
              :"memory"
              );
vmxon_success = 0;
asm volatile("vmxon_finish:\n");
```

The value of rflags_value after this code is: 515

which means that the carry flag is on (And therefore, the address is probably invalid - no idea why).

Any suggestions? Tried almost everything =[

Comment: Is this gcc?  If so, then you really shouldn't do this as multiple asm statements.  As an example, there is no guarantee that flags will be unchanged between statements.  Have you examined the -S output?  How about something like this (forgive the formatting): `bool res; 
asm volatile("vmxon %[physaddr] \n\t"
             "seta %[res]"
   : [res] "=r" (res)
   : [physaddr] "g"(&physicalAddr)
   : "cc", "memory");

Comment: What is that -S thing? Could you explain?

Comment: Using -S causes gcc to output the assembly code that is generated to a human readable file (see http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html).  Looking at the actual assembly that gets generated may give you clues about what's going wrong.

Comment: I actually tried calling to vmxon using asm file (nasm x64) but still no luck =[. What else could it be?